# In Maven, how can I clean external dirs on dev-build but keep default clean behaviour on any build?

Tags: maven, build, maven-3

This is my approach, but it doesn't work. In fact the plugin seems to ignore filesets when used inside `execution` tag.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution><!--Execute only on dev build-->
            <id>clean-dev-files</id>
            <configuration>
                <skip>${not-dev-build}</skip>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>/tmp/devdir</directory>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution><!--Execute always. So that target dir is cleaned on all builds. -->
            <id>default-clean-behaviour</id>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html may help

Answer (score 0):

I tested your configuration and it works fine for me.

Please try to invoke the maven clean plugin for dev-build using its execution id as shown below:

```
mvn clean:clean@clean-dev-files
```

The above command should do the regular clean as well as delete your external directory. For rest of your builds, you can just use

```
mvn clean
```

and it should not delete the external directory.

Comment: It's nice proposal. But I think this would execute only the clean plugin, and not the full clean lifecycle. So it won't be additional to clean defaults.